# How to renew VMware certificate in Veeam

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, certificate, veeam

I had to reinstall the vcenter appliance. Since that the Veeam backupjobs fail with the error:

> Task failed error: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Presumably the certificate was renewed.

How can I import it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Veeam

- go to `backup infrastructure`
- Choose your VMware ESXi Server, right click, and select `properties`
- A dialog comes up
- There click on `finish`
- When there is a new certificate you will be prompted an you can install it